# REST API: "INVALID_SESSION_ID" with valid token

Tags: rest-api, oauth2, rest, php

I'm having some trouble accessing API endpoints using a valid token that I *just* got from the OAuth process.

I'm passing data as I think I should and am trying to access any endpoint at this point (Actually, I need to create a case, but even getting `/limits` to work would be nice)

```
$url = $domain . '/services/data/v34.0/sobjects/limits';

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Authorization: OAuth $token",
        "Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '');

return curl_exec($curl);
```

My developer instance is at `na16.salesforce.com` and if I understand it correctly, I need to be using that domain for my API calls.

I feel like maybe I'm just missing an extra header item that I need to send or something, but I'm having no luck finding what that needs to be.

Perhaps I need to create some kind of session first? Either way, I'm having no luck figuring out what that is after a whole lot of searching.

The code above is the entirely of my call to the API. What is missing here?

Comment: I am having this exact issue for many days now. Did you find any resolution? Thanks

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't really know *why* it started working. The code is exactly the same as above and it works fine now. Sorry I can't be much more help.

Comment: Haha, I've seen that answer more than once ;) - thanks for the response.

Comment: make sure you're using the access token, and not the refresh token.

Answer (score 2):

Re this line:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Authorization: OAuth $token", "Content-type: application/json"));
```

I think the Auth header should be **Bearer** + Token

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Authorization: Bearer $token", "Content-type: application/json"));
```

See a more detailed example [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_oauth.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that as well. The docs seem to say you can use either and they both give the same response.

Comment: Have you tried using a session id - you can use that as the token and it works as well - that way, you can hopefully work out if it's the code, or the oauth process

Comment: No, I haven't. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that today.

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem occurred because I had initialized my salesforce object in the parent context and the session went stale before I called that code again.

```
    sf = Salesforce(
        username=config.get('USERNAME', ''),
        password=config.get('PASSWORD', ''),
        security_token=config.get('SECURITY_TOKEN', ''),
        sandbox=config.get('SANDBOX', False)
    )
```

Moving the initialization of this object inside the called function allowed it to be set up on each call and therefore the session didn't expire.